# Logback not creating the output logging file

Tags: java, logback

I am trying to add Logback logging for my application . The code doesnt create the logging file .

I have added logback core and log back classic . Added logback.xml in resource folder . Made sure resource folder  in build path .

```
<configuration debug="true">
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
     <encoder >
        <pattern>%relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
 </appender>
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
     <file>/data/csrt/log_path/logFiles/logFile.log</file>
     <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
         <fileNamePattern>/data/csrt/log_path/logFiles/logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log</fileNamePattern>
         <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
         <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
     </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder >
        <pattern>%relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
 </appender>
 <root level="INFO">
     <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
     <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
 </root>
</configuration>
```

Java code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainVerticle.class);
```

I am expecting a log file to get created in each of the runs. It is not happening

Comment: I have added the below dependencies        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
  </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

log file is created lazily, please try to add an actual log statement, such as:

```
LOGGER.info("test");
```

Comment: application has lot of logger statements . The statements come to the console output in this format 19/06/22 22:58:32 INFO class name : Log Message but no log file is created

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually logging something?  Just creating a Logger object isn't going to produce any output or create any log files. You have to actually call `LOGGER.info/warn/error()` to get any logging to occur.

If you ARE calling `LOGGER.info/warn/error()` elsewhere in the code in your MainVerticle class, and so that's not the problem, make sure that your program is running as a user that has the rights to write to the log location you are specifying.  Also, I don't think that RollingFileAppender will create directories, so make sure that the directory into which you want to write the log file to be written actually exists.

You also create a log sink to log to the console (thanks for extending your question to show us your logback.xml file).  Are you seeing logging to the console?  If not, then you know that the problem has nothing to do with file I/O, or the file path or anything like that, as you're not getting logging at all.

Comment: The application has hundreds of logging statements . which i chose not to give here  .  The application logs it to console but in the below format 19/06/22 22:58:32 INFO class name : Log Message . not the one specified by the logger and the log file doesnt get created

Comment: I am thinking i may be doing some thing wrong with logback.xml or missing a depenedency not sure what is happening . Unfortunately  i cant run this in local to debug , the code only runs on a cluster